# How to include SDL2 and SDL_image on both Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been developing using C++ and SDL2 on Linux and have been using the following form to include SDL2 in my headers :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

However, I now have need to develop on Windows too, which has a different include declaration.  I've read up on it as best I can and have successfully included SDL using **#include "SDL.h"** and passing **-I/usr/include/SDL2** into my makefile.  This works fine for SDL, but seems to break SDL_image.

Using :

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
```

results in a long list of errors starting with

```
undefined reference to `IMG_Load'
```

Using

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

with the **-lSDL2_image** flag results in

```
undefined reference to symbol 'SDL_FreeSurface'
```

Both of these errors I know are to do with SDL_image.  The only thing that seems to work is

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

with the **-lSDL2 -lSDL2_image** when compiling, but I'd rather avoid that if possible so that I don't have to use #ifdef to compile on both Linux and Windows.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: In all but your last attempt, you're using SDL 1 or mixin it with SDL 2. You *really don't* want to do that. Also, how is the Windows include section different from the Linux one?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your assessment.  I don't have SDL1 installed and the SDL bit compiles fine.  The header file for SDL2 is called SDL.h and it is correct to use #include "SDL.h" to refer to SDL2.  The differentiator is that it is in the SDL2 directory, which I specify in -I/usr/include/SDL2.  The header file for SDL_image is also in /usr/include/SDL2 which is why I'm not sure why #include "SDL_image" doesn't work.  The include statement for Windows is #include "SDL.h"

Comment: Error `undefined reference to` is symtom for missed *linking* directives to compiler. Include directories has nothing common with this error (unless you use wrong header, which is unlikely your case).

Comment: First of all, you can use your first include form just as well (but second is 'officially' recommended, with include paths coming from `sdl2-config --cflags`), just set correct include path. And second, even if by some magic you've got SDL1.2 in your include path and included them, it shouldn't be as you describe it since these symbol names are the same. Can you provide minimal example or at least full compilation and linking lines?